# Get the start and end dates of the previous month the query is run with PostgreSQL/intervals

Tags: postgresql, interval

I am looking for a way to get the start and end datetime for the previous month the query is run that I can reuse inside a query.

I was looking at `interval` but I would like the query to work out that if I run the query in March 2021 that I am looking for data from '2021-02-01 00:00:00' to '2021-02-28 23:59:59'.

Is this possible using `interval` or something similar or does it need an intermediate step?

Comment: Do you have a `timestamp` column in the table that you want to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to apply a condition on a column in the table you can use:

```
where timestamp_column >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - interval '1 month'
  and timestamp_column <  date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
```

`date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - interval '1 month'` gives you the start of the previous month. In March this would be 2021-02-01

`date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)` gives you the start of "this month" so in March this would be `2021-03-1` as the comparison for the upper limit is done using `<` it will include everything on the last day of February (including `23:59:59.9999999` which your desired condition would not include).